# orphanRemoval generates additional delete-statement

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following:

```
class A {

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "a")
    private Set<B> bs;
 
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")
 private Set<C> cs;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@IdClass(BKey.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
class B {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;

    @Id
    private String anotherKey;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class BKey implements Serializable {

    private A a;

    private String anotherKey;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
@IdClass(CKey.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
class C {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;

    @Id
    private String anotherKey;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CKey implements Serializable {

    private A a;

    private String anotherKey;
}
```

when I'm doing

`myRepo.save(objectA);`

it does what I need actually, if there are new items of class B, then insert-statement is generated, if some of them removed, then delete-statement is generated because of orphanRemoval.
But for some reason when new items are added for class C, then correct insert-statements are generated but in addition one delete-statement is generated which always remove first added item. I totally don't get this. Any reasons what can cause this ? When I remove orphanRemoval from B, then the delete-statement is not generated which is expected behaviour. But as you see there is just no relation between B and C.

Answer (score 0):

OMG I didn't realize that

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

does save of A again. After removing `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` everything works as expected.